# How can I create unit tests involving collections in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections

I have a number of methods in C# which return various collections which I wish to test. I would like to use as few test APIs as possible - performance is not important. A typical example is:

```
HashSet<string> actualSet = MyCreateSet();
string[] expectedArray = new string[]{"a", "c", "b"};
MyAssertAreEqual(expectedArray, actualSet);
```

//...

```
void MyAssertAreEqual(string[] expected, HashSet<string> actual)
{
    HashSet<string> expectedSet = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach {string e in expected)
    {
        expectedSet.Add(e);
    }
    Assert.IsTrue(expectedSet.Equals(actualSet));
}
```

I am having to write a number of signatures according to whether the collections are arrays, Lists, ICollections, etc. Are there transformations which simplify this (e.g. for converting an array to a Set?).

I also need to do this for my own classes. I have implemented HashCode and Equals for them. They are (mainly) subclassed from (say) MySuperClass. Is it possible to implement the functionality:

```
void MyAssertAreEqual(IEnumerable<MySuperClass> expected, 
                      IEnumerable<MySuperClass> actual);
```

such that I can call:

```
IEnumerable<MyClassA> expected = ...;
IEnumerable<MyClassA> actual = ...; 
MyAssertAreEqual(expected, actual);
```

rather than writing this for every class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both NUnit and MSTest (probably the other ones as well) have a CollectionAssert class

- [CollectionAssert (NUnit 2.5)](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5.1)
- [CollectionAssert for MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx)

Comment: Thank you (I am using MSTest, I think). This looks like what I need. We are planning to move to NUnit RSN

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET 3.5 you can use the Enumerable.SequenceEqual method.

```
Assert.IsTrue(seqA.SequenceEqual(seqB));
```

You should use OrderBy on both sequences prior to calling SequenceEqual if you only care about the elements being equal and not the order.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Enumerable.SequenceEqual instead of IEnumerable?

Comment: @Michael: It's an extension method, so you can just use `seqA.SequenceEqual(seqB)`. It's *very important* to note that you need to use `OrderBy(...)` to have meaningful comparisons (you care about the existence of elements, but not about the order).

Comment: Edited answer to reflect good suggestions from @Michael and @280Z28

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4) that comes with NUnit.

It asserts against the two collections and compares the items within the collection