# Are there MSTest collection constraints that are similar to NUnits

Tags: nunit, mstest

I am working on a project utilizing MSTest and I need similar constraints for testing arrays/lists that NUnit provides (http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.4.8)

Is there anything similar built-in or as an add-on to the MSTest framework?

Comment: Link seems broken, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help.

[Collection Contrainsts in C# here at Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204922/how-can-i-create-unit-tests-involving-collections-in-c)

And this, the specific class that the question is relating to.

[CollectionAssert Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert_members.aspx)

The asserts are very similar to that provided in the NUnit test.

regards

Bob.

Comment: wow, thanks. the way it is named made it difficult to discover.